# Using strip when scraping with scrapy python

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am having some difficulty stripping unwanted characters from data I have scraped using scrapy.

Example data:

> 'Premium Terraced Studio',  '51 weeks (09/09/2017 - 31/08/2018) Room -
>   Lease',   '',   '',   '',   '',   '',   '',   'Premium Plus Terraced
>   Studio',   '51 weeks (09/09/2017 - 31/08/2018) Room - Lease',  '',
>   '',   '',   '',

It was a lot messier and had new lines but I used this, which kind of cleaned it up:

```
[s.strip() for s in response.xpath('//div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/div/text()').extract()]
```

I have also tried this, which didn't help much:

```
[s.strip("''\n") for s in response.xpath('//div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/div/text()').extract()]
```

Any thoughts would be apprenticed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `filter` with `None`, i.e.:

```
some_list = list(filter(None, response.xpath('//div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/div/text()').extract()))
```

---

Update:

I normally use `lxml` to parse `html`, here's an example that may help you:

```
import requests
from lxml import etree

my_url = 'https://www.collegiate-ac.com/uk-student-accommodation/glasgow/claremont-house/rooms-rent'
html = requests.get(my_url, allow_redirects=True).text
tree = etree.HTML(html)
divs = tree.xpath("//div[@class='lease-type']/text()")
for div_text in divs:
    print div_text
```

---

Output:

```
51 weeks (09/09/2017 - 31/08/2018) Room - Student Lease
51 weeks (09/09/2017 - 31/08/2018) Room - Student Lease
51 weeks (09/09/2017 - 31/08/2018) Room - Student Lease
51 weeks (09/09/2017 - 31/08/2018) Room - Student Lease
...
```

Comment: Thanks! That is returning `<filter at 0x2202e8a8cf8>`?

Comment: Thanks for that one. Unfortunately, that returns the same value as `response.xpath('//div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/div/text()').extract()` i.e. with lots of white-space and newlines

Comment: Unfortunately, it's hard for me to help you debug your code without having the big picture. You may want to post the real url so I can test further.

Comment: Thanks! This is the one I've been using - https://www.collegiate-ac.com/uk-student-accommodation/glasgow/claremont-house/rooms-rent - hopefully that should help?

Comment: What are you trying to extract from that page? all listing details?

Comment: Notice that `filter(None, ['1','1', ''])` gives `<filter object at 0x0000000005A97550>` but that `list(filter(None, ['1','1', '']))` gives `['1', '1']`. (@PedroLobito)

Comment: @Maverick Have a look at the new update, it uses `lxml` to parse `html`.

Comment: Thanks @PedroLobito! I have also figured this out by adjusting the x path `response.xpath('//div/div/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/div[1]/text()').extract()`

Comment: @Maverick Great, I'm glad you solved the problem. GL